# How to play animations sequentially with ObjectAnimator using path

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to run the animation one by one using the path for ObjectAnimator, but the new animation starts its motion from the original position, how can I continue the animation from the previous position.

```
    val path = Path().apply {
        lineTo(randomWidth(), randomHeight())
    }

    val path2 = Path().apply {
        lineTo(randomWidth(), randomHeight())
    }

    list.add(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(catchView, View.X, View.Y, path).setDuration(2000)
    )
    list.add(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(catchView, View.X, View.Y, path2).setDuration(2000)
    )

    bouncer.playSequentially(list)
    bouncer.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

To continue the animation from the previous position, you will have to provide previous position as initial value for 2nd path using `moveTo()`. Without `moveTo()` default `initial point(0,0)` is set.

For Example :

```
val path = Path().apply {
        lineTo(randomWidth(), randomHeight())
    }

    val path2 = Path().apply {

        moveTo(randomWidth(), randomHeight())
        lineTo(randomWidth()+yourDesireValue, randomHeight()+yourDesireValue)
    }

    list.add(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(catchView, View.X, View.Y, path).setDuration(2000)
    )
    list.add(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(catchView, View.X, View.Y, path2).setDuration(2000)
    )

    bouncer.playSequentially(list)
    bouncer.start()
```

Note: From docs of `lineTo()`

> Add a line from the last point to the specified point (x,y). If no
> moveTo() call has been made for this contour, the first point is
> automatically set to (0,0).